# MongoDB 2dsphere index error

Tags: mongodb, geojson

Error creating index for table 'MSParcels': WriteConcern detected an error 'Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:

```
{ type: "Polygon", coordinates: 
    [ [ [ -122.118466012, 47.6511409501, 0.0 ], 
        [ -122.118687874, 47.6508529655, 0.0 ], 
        [ -122.118817718, 47.650852731, 0.0 ], 
        [ -122.118890754, 47.650852592, 0.0 ], 
        [ -122.118891979, 47.651140118, 0.0 ], 
        [ -122.118703033, 47.6511404878, 0.0 ], 
        [ -122.118466012, 47.6511409501, 0.0 ] ] ] }
```

Problem is, I'm copying from SQL Server where identical coordinates pass STIsValid

Using C# driver MongoDB.Driver.Builders.IndexKeys.GeoSpatialSpherical

Mongo version 2.4.4

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geojson isn't valid for mongodb- it only accepts x,y and not z coordinates (altitude).  This is because it only has 2D indexing / querying capabilities.

You need to remove the z coordinates from the geojson document to be something like:

```
{ type: "Polygon", coordinates: 
    [ [ [ -122.118466012, 47.6511409501], 
        [ -122.118687874, 47.6508529655], 
        [ -122.118817718, 47.650852731], 
        [ -122.118890754, 47.650852592], 
        [ -122.118891979, 47.651140118], 
        [ -122.118703033, 47.6511404878], 
        [ -122.118466012, 47.6511409501] ] ] }
```

There has been a feature request to improve this - please vote for: [SERVER-9220](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9220)

Comment: No problems - can you mark as answered to help others with the same issue?

Comment: That feature was implemented in MongoDB 3.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Your coordinates invalid. A geojson polygon is a array of arrays of arrays with two coordinates not three (the additional 0.0)